# QWebView::setUrl not working

Tags: c++, qt

I'm new in this Q&A site and in the Qt world. I want to integrate a web page in my application. I want to get a tag input's value, but it's not working, can you help me?

This is my class's constructor:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
: QWidget(parent)
{
QVBoxLayout *container = new QVBoxLayout;


QWebView *cart = new QWebView();
QWebPage *page = new QWebPage();

cart->setUrl(QUrl("http://www.mysite.com/"));


QWebFrame *main = cart->page()->mainFrame();

QWebElement document = main->documentElement();
QWebElement t1 = document.findFirst("input[name=myname]");
QString storedText = t1.attribute("value", "defaultvalue");

qDebug() << "T1 value:" << storedText;
storedText = t1.attributeNS(QString::Null(), "value");
qDebug() << "T1 ns value:" << storedText;
QVariant v = t1.evaluateJavaScript("this.value");
qDebug() << "Javascript value:" << v.toString(); // ok. returns c

container->addWidget(cart);

setLayout(container);
this->show();
}
```

The web page appears in my application but the output on the command line is this:

```
T1 value: ""
T1 ns value: ""
Javascript value: ""
```

The variable storedText has the value `""`

Answer (score 6):

Thats because after setting URL using `QWebView::setUrl()`, you must wait for `QWebView::loadFinished(bool ok)` `signal` before retrieving any data. See the [documentation](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qwebview.html).

So move your retrieval code for element's information in a `slot` for `QWebView::loadFinished()` `signal`.

Comment: Thank you very much, now it work! 
I imagined that was that, but I didn't know that I needed a SIGNAL.


Thank You again.